# STRCMP on numeric strings

Tags: c, strcmp

so I have 3 variables:

```
char fromAge[4];
char toAge[4];
char age[4];
```

They can all have a number between 18 and 100 (include 18 and 100).
When I give them the follwing values, the following statement is wrong for some reason:

```
fromAge[4] = 18;
toAge[4] = 100;
age[4] = 25;
if (strcmp(age, fromAge) >= 0 && strcmp(age, toAge) <= 0)
{
//actions
}
```

It thinks "age" isn't smaller or equals to "toAge".
Any suggestions for why?

edit:
This is how I assign the variables, I leave 1 byte for '\0'

```
scanf("%s", fromAge);
scanf("%s", toAge);
```

and age is 2,5,'\0'

Comment: the index in C starts from 0. so fromAge[4] doesn't exist. The defined `fromAge[4]` is only from `fromAge[0]` to `fromAge[3]` and so on.

Comment: This isn't how you assign numeric values to a character array.  Use atoi()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcmp` compares strings by comparing the individual characters from left to right and it will return as soon as two characters differ. As the character `'1'` is less than the character `'2'`, the string "100" will be considered less than the string "25".

Try this code and give the input "100" and "25"

```
int main()
{
  char toAge[4] = {0};
  char age[4]={0};
  scanf("%3s", age);
  scanf("%3s", toAge);

  // Using string compare
  if (strcmp(age, toAge) < 0)
    printf("\"%s\" is less than \"%s\"\n", age, toAge);
  else if (strcmp(age, toAge) > 0)
    printf("\"%s\" is greater than \"%s\"\n", age, toAge);
  else
    printf("\"%s\" is equal to \"%s\"\n", age, toAge);

  // Using integer compare
  if (atoi(age) < atoi(toAge))
    printf("%s is less than %s\n", age, toAge);
  else if (atoi(age) > atoi(toAge))
    printf("%s is greater than %s\n", age, toAge);
  else
    printf("%s is equal to %s\n", age, toAge);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
"100" is less than "25"
100 is greater than 25
```

As you can see the function `atoi` can be used to get the result you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking strings, which means you are checking it alphabetically, and indeed : "2" does not come before "1" in the alphabet: in ASCII, the value for "2" is 50, while the value for "1" is 49, and indeed: 50 does not come before 49.

Therefore it's always a bad idea to use numbers a strings, just treat them as numbers and everything should be fine:

```
int FromAge;
int ToAge;
...
```

Good luck